# NSOpenPanel get filename in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, selector, php-ziparchive

When I create an NSOpenPanel, like this:

```
int i;

NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

if ([openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton)
{
    NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];

    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
    {
        NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(fileName);
        NSString *catched = fileName;
        [self performSelector:@selector(decompresss2z:) withObject:catched];
    }
}
```

And when I log `fileName`, it is correct and prints my file full directory, but when I try to use it with my void, it gets like super weird letters, like ÿ^0f totally random. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "use it with my void"?  Also, runModalForDirectory:file:types: is depreciated in 10.6, you should be using runModal instead.

Answer (score 15):

There's nothing wrong with that code.  Actually, there are a number of things that are less than ideal about that code, but nothing that will make it not work.  What does the decompresss2z: function look like?

If this were my code, I'd make the following changes:

1. `runModalForDirectory:file:` is deprecated; you should use `runModal` instead.
2. `filenames` is deprecated; you should use `URLs` instead (you can call `path` on each URL to get the filename).
3. `NSLog`'s parameter needs to be a format string, or else odd things can happen.
4. You should use fast enumeration (with the `in` keyword), rather than looping through a container with an index. It's not only more efficient, it's less code (and less code is better).
5. There's no reason to call `performSelector:withObject:` here; just call the method normally.

Rewritten, it would look like this:

```
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )  // See #1
{
    for( NSURL* URL in [openDlg URLs] )  // See #2, #4
    {
        NSLog( @"%@", [URL path] );      // See #3
        [self decompresss2z:[URL path]]; // See #5
    }
}
```

Again, though, none of these changes will change your actual issue.  In order to help further, we need to see more code.  Specifically, I'd like to see what decompressss2z: looks like.

Comment: Finally an updated answer. Every other places are still the deprecated method.